Exchange-Online Send-MailMessage cmdlet now obsolete
Situation:  I have migrated my company's email over to Microsoft Exchange.  As such I have been familiarizing myself with Powershell, because I want to be able to script the process of adding users.
What I want to do*:  After creating a new user I want to notify the new user's supervisor of the username and password they are to use.  Ideally, I want to BCC myself so I have confirmation of the new user(s) and credentials as well as exclusively using the command line.
The problem:  When testing out the Send-MailMessage cmdlet in Powershell I get the following error:
WARNING: The command 'Send-MailMessage' is obsolete. This cmdlet does not guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers. While there is no immediate replacement available in PowerShell, we recommend you do not use Send-MailMessage at this time. See https://aka.ms/SendMailMessage for more information.
Send-MailMessage: Error in processing. The server response was: Requested action aborted: local error in processing

My question(s):

What do I not understand about how to use the Microsoft Exchange Online module in Powershell to send an email?
Is this something that Microsoft is permanently removing?

I tried using the following test script:
Send-MailMessage `
    -From "myemail@domain.tld" `
    -To "mycoworkeremail@domain.tld" `
    -SmtpServer "outlook.office365.com" `
    -Subject "Test Email" `
    -Body "Test message"


Microsoft can't remove the ability to send emails thru smtp servers, they're just warning you it is not safe. When they tell you to "See https://aka.ms/SendMailMessage for more information." they really mean it, you should simply just open the link to learn more...

see: PowerShell send-mailmessage deprecated - future consequences for people still relying on it?

This has been answered here:
PowerShell send-mailmessage deprecated - future consequences for people still relying on it?
Essentially Microsoft has deprecated the feature.
